# Compile error when running on another machine

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I am having a problem with a workbook.  It works fine on my machine but when it is run by someone else it is giving a problem with an error message "Compile error  can't find project or library"- thing is, it is doing it on a Mid$ string command!

Anyone know what could cause this?  Is there a setting they need somewhere?  The code was written in Excel 2010 and they are running Excel 2010

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is caused when you have a missing reference. Have a look in Tools > References on the machines that are throwing the error. You should see that certain references are prefixed with MISSING.

These libraries will need to be installed on the other machines in order to use them, alternatively, you could try late binding if they have an earlier version of the reference you are using.

If the above doesn't work, I have experienced this problem when there is a failed installation on the machine. None of the references are missing, but upon opening Excel a (usually unrelated) application gets stuck in a failed install loop. If this is what is happening, you'll need to rectify the failed installation.